# Process files while downloading with aria2

Tags: bash, shell, directory, filesystems, monitoring

I am downloading zip folders from the internet regularly to a specific folder and each time the download process is finished (I do it using `aria2` as download manager) I want to run a specific bash script that will process the data.

Any idea on how to proceed? I have found several references but I am not familiar with bash scripting. Btw, I am working on Ubuntu 16.04.

As example, I have the following folder

[image]

Each time the download process is finished, I want to run `script.sh`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#event-hook), aria2 provides an event hook called `--on-download-complete`:

> Event Hook
>
> aria2 provides options to specify arbitrary command after specific
>   event occurred. Currently following options are available:
>   `--on-bt-download-complete`, `--on-download-pause`, `--on-download-complete`. `--on-download-start`, `--on-download-error`, `--on-download-stop`.

So, if you already have `script.sh` as you mention, simply call aria using

```
aria2c --on-download-complete script.sh http://example.org/file.iso
```

Comment: is it possible to add pass additional parameters to script.sh?